# Как перебрать свойства объекта в цикле и присвоить им значения?

Tags: python

```
"data": [
    ["str", "str", "str", 1, 1, 1, "str", "str", 1, "str", null, "str", "str", "str", 0.5, 137, "str", "date", 98000184, "str", "str", "date", 137, 137, "str", "str", 3, "date"],
Этих массивов 300 шт.
```

У меня есть большой набор данных в массивах.
Мне нужно, чтобы эти массивы стали объектами.
Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
def array_to_obj(self, url):
    asset = assets()

    for array in self.read_assets(url):
        if array[0] != None:
            asset.SECID = str(array[0])
        if array[1] != None:
            asset.BOARDID = str(array[1])
        if array[2] != None:
            asset.SHORTNAME = str(array[2])
        if array[3] != None:
            asset.PREVPRICE = float(array[3])
      ............................. И т.д.
```

Свойств там 28 штук, а каждое писать не хочется.

Так вот, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что какой бы способ присвоения свойствам значений вы не выбрали, хотя бы один раз их описать все равно придётся?

Comment: `obj.__dict__.update(notNoneDict())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого удобно вынести имена нужных атрибутов в список, и использовать его в цикле вместе с [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr), а также getattr и hasattr. Пример:

```py
class MyClass:
    property_names = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'other', 'gh', 'ij']

    def __init__(self):
        # Если начальные данные не важны, то здесь тоже
        # можно присвоить все значения в цикле
        self.ab = 1
        self.cd = 2
        self.ef = 3
        self.other = 4
        self.gh = 5
        self.ij = 6

    def set_data(self, array):
        if len(array) != len(MyClass.property_names):
            raise ValueError('Bad data length!')
        for i in range(len(array)):
            value = array[i]
            # В коде вопроса None пропускаются
            if value is not None:
                key = MyClass.property_names[i]
                setattr(self, key, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyClass(%s)' % ','.join([str(getattr(self, key)) for key in MyClass.property_names])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Загрузка данных:

```py
o = MyClass()
print(o)
o.set_data([None, -2, 'ef', None, 3.1415, 2.7182])
print(o)
```

Получается:

> MyClass(1,2,3,4,5,6)
>
> MyClass(1,-2,ef,4,3.1415,2.7182)

И это можно легко обернуть в цикл по массиву со множеством объектов.

---

#### Альтернативы

Советую посмотреть в сторону [Named Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), которые позволяют легко обращаться к полям объекта как по индексу, так и по имени, а имена полей задаются списком (но это тьюпл, соответственно, неизменяемый объект, что недостаток в данном случае). Или
[Data Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) из Python 3.7.